# Font not rendering (using bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

So I am trying to use a custom font, actually I'm using two of them. However, only one of them is rendering in the website. I tried switching them around to make sure it wasn't the reference to the second font, but then it worked fine so it wasn't that. I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. Oswald is the font rendering just fine. Quattracento is the one not working. Any advice?

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Arrow's Edge - Our Services</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>    
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- fonts -->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quattrocento' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>


<body>
<!-- HTML for navbar -->
<nav class="navbar nav navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand logo-fit" href="index.html"><img id ="logo-bar" src="images/logo-bar.png" alt="Arrow's Edge Logo"></a>

  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
</div>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-inverse navbar-right collapse navbar-collapse">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="our-services.html">Our Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">About Us<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu inverse-dropdown">
            <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="our-story.html">Our Story</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        </ul>    
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
</nav>

<!-- end of HTML for navbar -->  

<!-- HTML for Our Servies page -->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-8 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-xs-offset-2 text-center design-header"><p>Web Design</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 text-center">
    <div class="custom"><span class="custom-header">Custom:</span> <br>
        <span class="my-text">We have a passion for designing new, cutting edge websites that are tailored to your specific needs. Need a site for a small business? A blog? A fan page? No problem! We have you covered.</span>
    </div>
</div>

</div>




</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Style for the Our Services page */

.design-header {
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
font-size: 40px;
margin-top: 15px;
border-bottom: 2px solid black;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.custom {
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 25px;
}


.custom-header {
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
font-size: 25px;
}


.my-text: {
font-family: 'Quattrocento', serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `:` just after your CSS selector, remove it.

```
/* Old CSS 
.my-text: {
   font-family: 'Quattrocento', serif;
} */

/* New CSS */
.my-text {
   font-family: 'Quattrocento', serif;
}
```

Comment: I've been trying to fix that for about an hour now. Can't believe I missed it. Thank you for the careful eye and catching it! You're a life saver